# Symfony: add IDs to option tags in multiselect

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

Version: Symfony 3

I have a multiselect in my form and its as below,

```
->add('roles', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'attr'  =>  array('class' => 'form-control',
    'style' => 'margin:5px 0;'),
    'choices' => 
    array
    (
        'ROLE_ADMIN' => array
        (
            $this->get('translator')->trans('Yes') => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
        ),
        'ROLE_TEACHER' => array
        (
            $this->get('translator')->trans('Yes') => 'ROLE_TEACHER'
        ),
        'ROLE_STUDENT' => array
        (
            $this->get('translator')->trans('Yes') => 'ROLE_STUDENT'
        ),
        'ROLE_PARENT' => array
        (
            $this->get('translator')->trans('Yes') => 'ROLE_PARENT'
        ),
    ) 
    ,
    'multiple' => true,
    'required' => true,
    ) )
```

and it sows as below in the front-end / web page,

```
<select multiple="multiple" style="margin:5px 0;" class="form-control" required="required" name="form[roles][]" id="form_roles">
<optgroup label="ROLE_ADMIN">
    <option value="ROLE_ADMIN">Yes</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="attr">
    <option value="checkp">id</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="ROLE_TEACHER">
    <option value="ROLE_TEACHER">Yes</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="ROLE_STUDENT">
    <option value="ROLE_STUDENT">Yes</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="ROLE_PARENT">
    <option value="ROLE_PARENT">Yes</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

Now I want to know how to add IDs for each options in the select. for an example,

```
<option id="parent" value="ROLE_PARENT">Yes</option>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [`choice_attr`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-attr) configuration. Something like this will work:

```
'choice_attr' => function($val) {
    list(, $roleName) = explode('_', $val, 2);

    return ['id' => strtolower($roleName)];
},
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I need to keep the same array for roles. Which means cannot change the code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying? You mean you can't have a fixed list of roles? If yes, I changed my answer accordingly. You can use any means of deciding the id-value from the option-value/key. I just used a map as an example.